# when adding custom header to inappbrowser window the image from local doesnt show up in sapui5 cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dom, sapui5

I have created a cordova app and made and iam calling external url using inappbrower window.open method.Using executeScript iam adding a custom header to the loader webpage.My code in app.controller.js is

```
iabRef = window.open('url', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop',changeHeader);
    function changeHeader(){
        iabRef.executeScript({
                code: "var newItem = document.createElement('div');
newItem.style.cssText = 'height:3rem;line-height:3rem;background:#0e3c60;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF';
var textnode = document.createTextNode('title');
newItem.appendChild(textnode);
var bButt = document.createElement('IMG');
bButt.src='img/left.png';
bButt.style.cssText = 'float:left;border:none;height:3rem;width:2.8rem;line-height:3rem;background:#0e3c60;';
newItem.insertBefore(bButt,newItem.childNodes[0]);
var list = document.querySelector('body');
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);"
            });
    }
```

Image is located in `img` folder my folder structure is

[image]

I have also tried putting image in same folder and giving `bButt.src='left.png';`

Comment: You do not have access to internal files from the InAppBrowser.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use an online image, or don't use an image at all (example, create the "image" with pure CSS)